# texworks is not launching!

Tags: texlive, texworks

I am using texlive as my Latex distribution which includes TexWorks as the primary editor. 
It has been working fine for few years now. But today, while trying to launch the texworks editor nothing is happened.

I am using the tex Live Menu to launch it. I checked the task manager in my windows distro 
for the texworks process but it is not started.

I wonder if somebody else have seen this issue before, and what solution/work around should I consider.

I have tex version 3.1415926 (Web2C 2011)

Comment: What happens if you double click on a `.tex` file?

Comment: nothing happens, that's the issue!

Comment: Press `Windows + r` to open the Run box. Then type `texworks` and check if the program starts.

Comment: i did that, but windows shouldn't find it because it is not in the path, i am using a portable version. The launching is done from the tex live menu!

Comment: Portable version! Sorry, I have no experience with it.

Comment: Try starting it from a command prompt window. You might get a useful error message at the prompt that would help pinpoint the actual problem.

Comment: even starting it from the command prompt doesn't show any error message!